# Fluorine Fx Server initialisation - c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluorinefx

I am trying to set up a RTMP server in Fluorine Fx and to receive web cam stream in the Flash example. I have not been able to get any recorded files saved to the website.

I have the source and I'm working in VS2010. I know which tcp/ip listener should be hit by the flash app. I am debugging their FluorineFx project source (rather than running directly on FluorineFx.dll).

It seems the listener is not initiated even which points to the Fluorine FX server not initiating itself.

I have the following standard config:

```
  <rtmpServer>
    <threadpool minWorkerThreads="0" maxWorkerThreads="25" idleTimeout="60000"/>
    <!-- Ping clients every "pingInterval" ms. Set to 0 to disable ghost detection code. -->
    <!-- Disconnect client after "maxInactivity" ms of not responding. -->
    <!-- Max. time in milliseconds to wait for a valid handshake. -->
    <rtmpConnection pingInterval="0" maxInactivity="60000" maxHandshakeTimeout="0"/>
    <rtmptConnection pingInterval="5000" maxInactivity="60000" maxHandshakeTimeout="5000"/>
    <rtmpTransport receiveBufferSize="4096" sendBufferSize="4096" tcpNoDelay="true"/>
  </rtmpServer>
```

I'm not sure what should kick the RTMP server into action.

Any ideas? Is it possible to bypass the server altogether and set up a RTMP listener in code?

Comment: Have you succeed to setup RTMP ?